# Can't close a print dialogue while clicking print button using javascriptexecutor in selenium Web driver firefox

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

I am currently working on automate functional testing using selenium web driver. I came across a scenario in which i need to click print button on a window (say A) which open a new window (say B). print dialogue is also got popped up with Window B. I need to close that print dialogue using java script executor.

I have tried this. but it did not work. My code:

```
public void handlePrintButtonScenario {
String parentWindow_A = driver.getWindowHandle(); //get the current window A handle
Printbutton().click(); //clicking print button

//switch focus of web driver to newly opened window B

for (String winhandle : driver.getWindowHandle()) {

driver.switchTo().window(winhandle);
}

//closing printdialoge
closeWindowByJS();

driver.close();// closing window B

driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow_A); // switching focus to window A

}

public void closeWindowByJS() {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    String script = "window.onbeforeunload = null;" + "window.close();";
    js.executeScript(script);
}
```

Right now what happened print dialogue and window B get closed when I execute the scenario for the first time by calling method closeWindowByJS(). I got exception at line driver.close() stating no such window found.

But when i rerun the scenario i.e. from the second time neither print dialogue nor Window B get closed. but focus got changed properly and scenario also running properly.

But i need to close that print dialogue first using javascriptexecutor and then close the window B. I dont need to close both by calling closeWindowByJS(). after this need to switch focus to window A.

Please help?

Comment: Please help me on this....urgently need the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use autoit 
Download the exe record the click on the button and record the code
Execute the code of autoit with the same java script executator

your driver.close()
should be after the code of switch window()

this should help

Comment: I can't use autoit as I am not authorized to use any exe. Could you please let me know any alternate solution. I am using Firefox as browser.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I need to first closed the print dialogue box that automatically popped up with window B. Since selenium driver can't handle these pop ups that's why I had to use JavaScript injection. After that I have to close window B. That can be handle by using driver.close(). I will try that what you have suggested. If you get any other workaround with this code or java script code . please let me know. And also I don't need to close window A when I finally switched to A. I just need to close print dialogue and then window B.

Comment: Hi Bansal shah, I have tried what you have suggested. Unfortunately it didn't work. Could you please suggest any other work around? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda old, but maybe this will help someone.

First, this piece of code gets only a single handle, `driver.getWindowHandles()` gets a `Set` of handles and can be iterated through.  Second, the webdriver instance switches to every single window, but doesn't really do anything with it.  Is this just to get to the end?

```
for (String winhandle : driver.getWindowHandle()) {

    driver.switchTo().window(winhandle);
}
```

If that's the case, instead of using a for loop, you can just cast the Set to an Arraylist and get the most recent one at the end of the list.

```
List<String> handles = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(handles.get(handles.size()-1);
```

That's not really the point here though.

Unfortunately, WebDriver cannot handle print dialogs.  These prompts are not related to the web page, and are a feature of the web browser.  There would be security issues if javascript could go access these prompts which are able to talk to your filesystem. If you're interested in knowing more about that, check out 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy
and
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security) for how javascript limitations stops it from interacting from these types of prompts.

Because the print prompt isn't a window and isn't seen by webdriver, when you try to close the print dialog you're actually closing Window B.  Different implementations for WebDriver can have different results with this behavior.  FirefoxDriver may not react the same way as ChromeDriver.  What you likely have to do is explicitly switch your webdriver back to the parent window A after you close window B.  You should use `driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow_A)` before attempting to make any interactions to ensure that WebDriver isn't sitting with no windows in focus.

IF you must interact with these prompts, and are using Java.  Then you CAN use java.awt.Robot to drive the desktop mouse to perform clicks.  But this can be a messy solution because you can only move to pixel coordinates.  So you'd have to position it to where you expect the buttons to be.  Here's a basic example of how to use Robot using absolute screen coordinates http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-robot-class-example-mouse-keystroke